# How does Quad Pumped Bus (QPB) work?

Tags: fsb

What is Quad Pumped Bus (QPB)? Is it just technology which multiplies FSB by 4 or what? Because I don't know if when I increase FSB it will affect QPB.

Comment: What does QPB stand for? FSB?

Comment: Quad Pumped Bus, and Front Side Bus I think. I always thought QPBs were a type of FSB or something.

Comment: So how does it rely on my memory?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Front Side Bus links your CPU to your memory. Since they are linked, they are synchronized. This is why it affects your memory if you increase the FSB. If you are increasing your FSB and have no idea why it affects your memory, I will stop you right there.

You need to read an overclocker guide.  Overclockers.com usually have good ones. Don't be fooled by the date on them.  Motherboard architecture hasn't significantly changed in a decade.

edit:
QPB is just the processor transferring data 4 times a clock cycle. The Pentium 4'ss and Core 2'ss used it.

Edit: Here is are some fun pictures for ya.

[image: X58]

[image: P35]

[image: AMD HT3]

Comment: Oh I see! FSB is magistral to the north chip (memory buffer) which then cooperates with ram clock. and QPB just makes FSB 4 times faster. And then north chip sends it to ram by it's fixed memory clock. Right am I? Could u correct me?

Comment: That's about right.

Comment: @oneat: Also, RAM uses similar tricks to transfer multiple values per clock cycle, that's where "DDR", "DDR2", "DDR3" come in.

Comment: Yeah, it gets even more fun than that too! We haven't even gotten into AMD's HyperTransport and Intel's Quick Path Interconnect. . .

Comment: Just like DDR means the RAM does two transfers per clock cycle, QPB means the CPU does four transfers per clock cycle.

Comment: Just repeating my answer huh? :)